# shape intersection with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I want to show only **intersection** of two shape by using **KineticJS**.
How can I do this?
I tried to do it like following link.
[HTML5 Canvas Clipping Region](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/). Is have any other way?

Comment: You should add details on the two shapes you are trying to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the solution based on Shmi.

```
   function makeShapeComposite(shape, operation) {
        shape.attrs._drawFunc = shape.attrs.drawFunc;
        shape.attrs.drawFunc = function (context) {
            context.save();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = operation;
            this.attrs._drawFunc.call(this, context);
            context.restore();
        };
        return shape;
    };   

   var pol=  makeShapeComposite(new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
           x: 250,
            y: 100,
            sides: 4,
            radius: 70,
            fill: '#00D2FF',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 2
        }), "destination-in");
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/sara9/2v7W2/5/

[Refer this tutorial.](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `globalCompositeOperation` to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/wbzwX/

```
ctx.fillStyle="#000";
ctx.fillRect(50,50,100,100);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in"; 
// this will use the fillstyle of the next drawn object. 
// "destination-in" will use the previous fillstyle.

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,50,30,0,Math.PI*2,false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle="#f00";
ctx.fill();​
```