# Javascript KineticJS Firefox Issue

Tags: html, firefox, kineticjs, internet-explorer-10

Im trying to do a composite operation on layers using KineticJS.
Everything works fine in Chrome, but nothing shows for firefox, or IE10
The code runs through without any errors.

You can see the issue here: 
http://clients.lilodesign.com/Lilo/Kinetic/

Chrome you should see a circle with a partial bit of the standard MS Blue Trees image showing through. In Firefox and IE10 you just get a blank screen.

You can view the code by viewing the source. Its all in-line and a very simple example to show the issue.
If you remove the following line:
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
Then you see the blue trees image with the ellipse on top of it as expected in all three browsers, so the code does "work".

Has anyone else experienced this and found a workaround?
I have searched and tried a couple of suggested solutions such as:
[shape intersection with KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767306/shape-intersection-with-kineticjs)

But all these still only seem to work in Chrome.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Tyrone.

Comment: Have you tried fixing this missing that appears in the console?? "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://clients.lilodesign.com/Lilo/Kinetic/"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I dont think thats the issue otherwise the page wouldnt work at all if I remove the globalCompositeOperation. Ive created another page http://clients.lilodesign.com/Lilo/Kinetic/test2.htm which has that line commented out so you can see what renders in Firefox and IE10. Its only the globalCompositeOperation that fails to work on FF&IE. Ive tried this in pure HTML5 and another Canvas Framework and it works fine, so Im guessing there is something odd in Kinetics Framework.

Comment: For the second link, I see the same thing both on Chrome and Firefox (can't say abt IE as this was tested on Mac) i.e. what you expect to be displayed

Comment: I see script tag in http://clients.lilodesign.com/Lilo/Kinetic/ is placed outside the body nor the head, try to move the script inside the body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used to be able to cheat by grabbing the context of a layer, but now it’s unreliable (as you’ve discovered).

You can still get verrrrry hacky and do it like this: :  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6fTQU/

*But don’t !*    (Even this hack doesn’t actually work on images with transparent pixels).

Instead, do it the official way by creating a Kinetic custom Shape Object.

Kinetic Shape gives you an official canvas and context to work with.

As a result, the globalCompositeOperation works fine (reliably!).

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LtxEe/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
        body{ background-color: ivory; }
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        buildLayer(img);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";


    function buildLayer(img){

        var myShape=new Kinetic.Shape({
            drawFunc:function(canvas){
                var ctx=canvas.getContext();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-atop";
                ctx.arc(150,150,60,0,Math.PI*2,false);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
            },
            x:0,
            y:0,
            width:img.width,
            height:img.height
        });
        layer.add(myShape);
        layer.draw();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, surprisingly even in IE10. Its a shame you cant use the inbuilt shape objects, but suppose you cant have everything done for you.